# Excel 2013 VBA wsheet.protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True

Tags: excel, vba

I ran a simple sub called `SetProtection()` one time on a macro enabled template.  The workbook has 9 tabs.  I ran the code so that `UserInterfaceOnly:=True`.  It works fine while the template is open.  I save and close the template. From a windows folder view, I double click the template file so that excel opens a new workbook. The `UserInterfaceOnly:=True` setting is forgotten by the new workbook.  I get an error when the value of a cell is changed when vba tries to change the value of another cell which is locked.

Lets say I edit the template file and savAs a macro enabled workbook.  If I edit the workbook the `UserInterfaceOnly:=True` setting continues to work.  VBA can make changes to locked cells.

Shouldn't `UserInterfaceOnly:=True` be passed on by an excel template file?

```
Sub SetProtection()

    Dim wSheet          As Worksheet
    Dim Pwd             As String
 Pwd = InputBox("Enter your password to protect all worksheets", "Password Input")
    For Each wSheet In Worksheets
        wSheet.Protect Password:=Pwd, UserInterfaceOnly:=True
    Next wSheet
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Protection.aspx

> The UserInterfaceOnly setting is not saved when you close the
>   workbook, so you need to set it when the workbook is opened. The best
>   place to do this is in the Workbook_Open event procedure.